# three.js opacity gradient

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was wondering, as the rgba is not supported in three.js (the alpha is not used), is there a way to make a face with an opacity gradient?

I saw it's probably possible with a ShaderMaterial, using custom attributes, but as I'm new in WebGL, I don't really understand yet.

```js
attributes = {
   // ...
   customColor: { type: 'v4', value: [] }
   // ...
};

var values_color = attributes.customColor.value;

for( var v = 0; v < vertices.length; v++ ) {
   // ...
   values_color[ v ] = new THREE.Vector4();
   // ...
}
```

I would like to do something like this, but with transparency: http://jsfiddle.net/FtML5/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `THREE.ShaderMaterial` with a custom vertex attribute for the alpha value. Here is a step by step guide -

1) In you vertex shader, declare a `attribute float` which will take the alpha value. Also declare a `varying float` in both vertex and fragment shader.

Vertex shader:

```
attribute float alphaValue;
varying float vAlphaValue;
```

Fragment shader:

```
varying float vAlphaValue;
```

2) Assign the alpha attribute value to the varying value in vertex shader.

Vertex shader:

```
vAlphaValue = alphaValue;
```

3) After all the calculation has been done, assign the alpha varying value to the alpha value of gl_FragColor.

Fragment shader:

```
gl_FragColor.a = vAlphaValue;
```

4) From host side, add an array with the length of total vertex. Here is the code sample -

```
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
var alphaArray = [];
var alphaArrayLength = vertices.length / 3;
for(var i = 0; i < alphaArrayLength; i++) {
      alphaArray.push(0.5);
}
```

5) Add a custom attribute for alpha value in the geometry and update it with the created array -

```
geometry.addAttribute('alphaValue', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(alphaArray), 1));
```

6) Create a THREE.ShaderMaterial -

```
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

            vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            transparent: true,
            vertexShader: document.
                getElementById('vertex_shader_for_face').text,
            fragmentShader: document.
                getElementById('fragment_shader_for_face').text
        });
```

7) Create the mesh with the geometry and material -

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution seems like using a custom shader and setting fragment opacity based on UV values.

Comment: Can you give an example?